# Prove that there are n roots by I.V.T

Tags: real-analysis

Let $$f(x) =a_1+a_2\cos x +a_3\cos 2x+...+a_{n+1}\cos nx.$$
If $|a_1|+|a_2|+...+|a_n |<|a_{n+1}|$ , state and prove a theorem on number of real roots of $f$on  $[0,\pi] $

$$f (0) = a_1+a_2 +a_3+....+a_{n+1}$$
$$f (\pi)=a_1- a_2 +a_3+.......+(-1)^n a_{n+1}$$

I know that theorem I.V.P must be used 
But I did not know it completely.

Can anyone help me solve this question step by step to understand it

Thanks

Comment: Why not try the special case where all the $a_j>0$? You could then look at the successive values of $x$ for which $\cos nx=\pm 1$, and see what the sign of $f(x)$ is there ...

Comment: And if I had to do it I'd try to do the cases $n=1,2$ as starters to get a feel for it.

Comment: You mean this When n=1   there is at least one root and the n=2 there is at least two root  ..etc to prove this statment

Comment: That would be my plan.